# How does smem calculate RSS, USS and PSS?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

Right now, I am trying to write a program, which should determine the memory usage of single process similar to smem, but not as fancy as smem. But I was wondering how smem determines the values USS, PSS and RSS. I would appreciate if could explain me in detail how to receive the necessary information.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply see the source code. It's written in python.
Basically,

```
USS = sum of /proc/<pid>/smaps Private_clean + Private_dirty
PSS = sum of /proc/<pid>/smaps Pss
RSS = sum of /proc/<pid>/smaps Rss
```