# What is the best way to calculate the real and combined memory usage of forked processes?

Tags: linux, memory, observability

I am working on a per process memory monitoring (Bash) script but it turns out to be more of a headache than I thought. Especially on forked processes such as PostgreSQL. There are a couple of reasons:

- RSS is a potential value to be used as memory usage, however this also contains shared libraries etc which are used in other processes
- PSS is another potential value which (should) show only the private memory of a process. Problem here is that PSS can only be retrieved from /proc//smaps which requires elevated capability privileges (or root)
- USS (calculated as Private_Dirty + Private_Clean, source [How does smem calculate RSS, USS and PSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890684/how-does-smem-calculate-rss-uss-and-pss)) could also be a potential candidate but here again we need access to /proc//smaps

For now I am trying to solve the forked process problem by looping through each PID's smaps (as suggested in https://www.depesz.com/2012/06/09/how-much-ram-is-postgresql-using/), for example:

```
for pid in $(pgrep -a -f "postgres" | awk '{print $1}' | tr "\n" " " ); do grep "^Pss:" /proc/$pid/smaps; done
```

*Maybe some of the postgres processes should be excluded, I am not sure.*

Using this method to calculate and sum the PSS and USS values, resulting in:

```
PSS: 4817 MB - USS: 4547 MB - RES: 6176 MB - VIRT: 26851 MB used
```

Obviously this only works with elevated privileges, which I would prefer to avoid. If these values actually represent the truth is not known because other tools/commands show yet again different values.

Unfortunately `top` and `htop` are unable to combine the postgres processes. `atop` is able to do this and seems to be (from a feeling) the most accurate with the following values:

```
NPROCS  SYSCPU  USRCPU    VSIZE   RSIZE    PSIZE  SWAPSZ   RDDSK    WRDSK   RNET    SNET   MEM  CMD         1/1
    27  56m50s  16m40s     5.4G    1.1G       0K   2308K      0K       0K      0       0   11%  postgres
```

**Now to the question: What is the suggested and best way to retrieve the most accurate memory usage of an application with forked processes, such as PostgreSQL?**

And in case `atop` already does an accurate calculation, how does `atop` get the to RSIZE value? Note that this value shown as root and non-root user, which would probably mean that /proc/<pid>/smaps is not used for the calculation.

Please comment if more information is needed.

EDIT: I actually found a bug in my pgrep pattern in my final script and it falsely parsed a lot more than just the postgres processes.

The new output now shows the same RES value as seen in `atop` RSIZE:

Script output:

```
PSS: 205 MB - USS: 60 MB - RES: 1162 MB - VIRT: 5506 MB
```

`atop` summarized postgres output:

```
NPROCS   SYSCPU   USRCPU    VSIZE    RSIZE    PSIZE   SWAPSZ    RDDSK    WRDSK    RNET    SNET    MEM   CMD
    27    0.04s    0.10s     5.4G     1.1G       0K    2308K       0K      32K       0       0    11%   postgres
```

But the question remains of course. Unless I am now using the most accurate way with the summarized RSS (RES) memory value. Let me know your thoughts, thanks :)